# Optimize SQL Script: getting range value from another table

Tags: sql, teradata

My script I believe should be running but it may not be that 'efficient' and the main problem is I guess it's taking too long to run hence when I run it at work, the whole session is being aborted before it finishes.

I have basically 2 tables
Table A - contains every transactions a person do

```
Person's_ID Transaction TransactionDate
---------------------------------------
123             A         01/01/2017
345             B         04/06/2015
678             C         13/07/2015
123             F         28/10/2016
```

Table B - contains person's ID and GraduationDate

What I want to do is check if a person is active. 
Active = if there is at least 1 transaction done by the person 1 month before his GraduationDate

The run time is too long because imagine if I have millions of persons and each persons do multiple transactions and these transactions are recorded line by line in Table A

```
SELECT
PERSON_ID
FROM
   (SELECT PERSON_ID, TRANSACTIONDATE FROM TABLE_A) A
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT CIN, GRAD_DATE FROM TABLE_B) B
ON A.PERSON_ID = B.PERSON_ID
AND TRANSACTIONDATE <= GRAD_DATE
WHERE TRANSACTIONDATE BETWEEN GRAD_DATE - INTERVAL '30' DAY AND GRAD_DATE;
```

*Table A and B are products of joined tables hence they are subqueried.

Comment: And what should the output look like?

Comment: Just as an FYI, your where clause will result in an inner join.  If you really want an outer join, the where clause needs to be moved to the on clause.

Comment: hi @GordonLinoff, the output I am expecting is a list of PERSON_ID who are "active" - this means with transactions within 30 days from the person's respective GraduationDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want active customers, I would try `exists`:

```
SELECT PERSON_ID
FROM TABLE_A A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM TABLE_B B
              WHERE A.PERSON_ID = B.PERSON_ID AND
                    A.TRANSACTIONDATE BETWEEN B.GRAD_DATE - INTERVAL '30' DAY AND GRAD_DATE
             );
```

The performance, though, is likely to be similar to your query.  If the tables were really tables, I would suggest indexes.  In reality, you will probably need to understand the views (so you can create better indexes) or perhaps use temporary tables.

Comment: Thanks, @GordonLinoff, trying to look into this. It run perfectly! Faster than my original script. Looking into the results now.

Answer (score 0):

A non-equi-join might be quite inefficient (no matter if it's coded as join or a Not Exists), but the logic can be rewritten to:

```
SELECT 
   PERSON_ID
FROM
 ( -- combine both Selects
    SELECT 0 AS flag -- indicating source table
       PERSON_ID, TRANSACTIONDATE AS dt
    FROM TABLE_A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS flag,
       PERSON_ID, GRAD_DATE
    FROM TABLE_B
 ) A
QUALIFY 
   flag = 1 -- only return a row from table B
AND Min(dt) -- if the previous row (from table A) is within 30 days
    Over (PARTITION BY PERSON_ID
          ORDER BY dt, flag
          ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND 1 Preceding) >= dt - 30
```

This assumes that there's only one row from table A per person, otherwise the `MIN` has to be changed to:

```
AND MAX(CASE WHEN flag = 1 THEN dt END) -- if the previous row (from table A) is within 30 days
    Over (PARTITION BY PERSON_ID
          ORDER BY dt, flag
          ROWS UNBOUNDED Preceding) >= dt - 30
```

Comment: hi @dnoeth, thanks for this! I'm now verifying whether the extracted data is correct. But just to understand, how is the min(dt) able to capture the within 30 days? the transaction should be within 30 days from the person's respective graduation date. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Joy: The `MIN` simply looks at the 'previous' row (could have been `MAX`, too, the result is equivalent to Standard SQL's `LAG`) and compares it to the current row. For a row from table_A the previous row holds the most recent date (assuming there's only one row per person, otherwise then MIN has to be changed, see my edit)